# How Can I Rotate the Raspberry Pi Screen 90°?

Tags: pi-zero-w, display

For a project, I need to rotate the screen of my Raspberry Pi Zero W with Raspberry Pi OS Lite 32 Bit operating system 90°, how can I do this?

Comment: what was the result of your research? ... how did it fail to resolve your issue?